# Unable to Get Report from 2nd row in grid view printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, crystal-reports

am working on reporting application.
after some learning I am able to generate report from the Database with Crystal Report.
But when the report for the 2nd invoice or bill is came into my record crystal report display no record whereas the record is existing with the database.

**GRIDVIEW DATA**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="billid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" CssClass="mydatagrid" 
                PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
                DataSourceID="Bill_View_Data" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="billid" HeaderText="Bill No." SortExpression="billid" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="billdate" HeaderText="Bill Date" SortExpression="billdate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTAL" HeaderText="Total Amount" SortExpression="TOTAL" ReadOnly="True" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Print" ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Select"
                                CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/images/Printer.png" Text="Print" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Height="24px" Width="24px" />
                        <ItemStyle Height="24px" Width="128px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="E-mail" Text="E-mail">
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="header"></HeaderStyle>
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager"></PagerStyle>
                    <RowStyle CssClass="rows"></RowStyle>
            </asp:GridView>
```

after displaying data in gridview. data look like image below.
[image: Data Grid View For Invoice]
when click on the 1st row print button the report displayed proper.
[image]
BUT when it comes to second and third it display report blank.
[image]

Code to get data and redirect to crystal report is

```
Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        Dim contactCell As TableCell = selectedRow.Cells(0)
        Dim contact As String = contactcell.Text
        Session("BallID") = contact
        Session("ContraxtID") = aggrmnt.SelectedValue
        Response.Redirect("~/Infinity/rpt/report.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

Report.ASPX page Code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim crystalReport As New ReportDocument()
    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"))
    Dim dsCustomers As RepoerDS = GetData()
    crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport
End Sub

Private Function GetData() As RepoerDS
    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("iNSbill").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "bill"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company_Filter", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("Companydetl")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bill_Identification", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("BallID")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContraxtID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("ContraxtID")
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            Using dsCustomers As New RepoerDS()
                sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "Bill_Report")
                Return dsCustomers
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Can you share your code of report.aspx where you are using session variables to generate report? Instead of session variable you should send the values of datagrid via query string to report.aspx did you debug the code to check what values are being passed to the report?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya updated the question with the report code page.

Comment: What did you observe while debugging? Are you getting proper values from gridview? Are getting proper values from session?

Comment: Yes getting them right. As report for the 1st record us generating easily

Comment: You need to check data for the 2nd row. Did you do that? Did you debug for 2nd row? The code looks ok. If you are getting correct values in session then may be the data is not returned correct from the db. Try running bill stored proc in sql management studio with the same parameters and see if you get proper data.